# Строка подключения для mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-winx64?

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, odbc

Описание ошибки:
`ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

Одна из причин: выставлена неправильная версия проекта.

- Если устанавливали 64 битную версию коннектора, в проекте ставите 64
- Если 32 битную -- то x86
  Также причиной может быть отсутствие установленного драйвера или его неправильное написание.

Страница загрузки https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**x64(64 битная)**

```
string source = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Database=spdf;User=root;Password=123;Option=3;";
```

[image: скрин]

И выберите нужную платформу(в зависимости от установленной версии)
mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-win**x64**.msi

**x86(32 битная)**

```
string source = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Database=spdf;User=root;Password=123;Option=3;"
```